# Replace content of appended div in Fancybox only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have used fancybox and appended a text div content to every images. The text div content appended is working well.But as I click to next button, the text div content is appended twice for each images.How to append that div content only once ?

```
$('.proBox').fancybox({

  thumbs : {
    autoStart : true,
    axis      : 'x'
  },
  idleTime : 0,
  buttons : [
    'info', 'close','thumbs'
  ],





    afterShow: function( instance, current ) {

        var url = window.location.href;
        var cat = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('#') + 1);
        var cats = cat.split('-');
        catId= cats[0];
        var toolbar = "<div id='tools'>"+$('#addscetion div').eq(this.index).html()+ "</div>";
            var index=catId+$("[data-fancybox-index]").html();
            $('.fancybox-slide').children(".imagecontainer").remove();

            // This is the div content that I am appending
            $(".fancybox-slide").append(toolbar);
            $(".fancybox-slide").append($('#'+index).html());

        },
      caption : function( instance, obj ) {
        return '<div><p class="fancy-nav"><a data-fancybox-prev title="Previous" tabindex="1">&lsaquo;</a> <a data-fancybox-next title="Next" tabindex="2">&rsaquo;</a> &nbsp; <span data-fancybox-index></span> of <span data-fancybox-count></span> images</p>' + $(this).find('.caption').html() + '</div>';
      },

      onInit: function(instance) {
                    instance.$refs.container.on('touchstart', '[data-fancybox-info]', function(e) {
                      e.stopPropagation();
                      e.preventDefault();

                      instance.$refs.container.toggleClass('fancybox-vertical-caption');
                    });
                    instance.$refs.container.on('mouseenter', '[data-fancybox-info]', function(e) {
                      instance.$refs.container.addClass('fancybox-vertical-caption');
                      instance.$refs.caption.one('mouseleave', function(e) {
                        instance.$refs.container.removeClass('fancybox-vertical-caption');
                      });

                    });
                    instance.$refs.container.on('click', '[data-fancybox-captionimg]', function(e) {
            $(".fancybox-image").attr("src",this.src);
          });
          instance.$refs.container.on('click', '[data-fancybox-captionbtn]', function(e) {
            $('.fancyRightCont').slideToggle('slow');
          });

                  }

    });
```

Comment: can you add full code which you tried

Comment: index.php
--------------------
<div class="swiper-wrapper swiperProgress">
<?php foreach ($cat_slno as $value) {
        if($value['image']!=""){
        ?>
<a class="proBox swiper-slide cutsomclass" title="sdsafdsa" href="uploads/<?=$value['image'];?>" data-fancybox="<?=$value['type'];?>">
<img src="uploads-new/<?=$value['small_image'];?>" />
<div class="caption">
<?=$value['description'];?>
</div>

Replace the appended section in previous post inside script file

$(".fancybox-slide").append("<div class='centerdivCont'></div>");
$(".fancybox-slide").append($('#'+index).html());

Comment: try the answer. hope it will helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can first remove appended html data from `.fancybox-slide` and then after append  HTML like this

```
$(".fancybox-slide").html('');
$(".fancybox-slide").append(toolbar);
$(".fancybox-slide").append($('#' + index).html());
```

Try below code.

```
$('.proBox').fancybox({

  thumbs: {
    autoStart: true,
    axis: 'x'
  },
  idleTime: 0,
  buttons: [
    'info', 'close', 'thumbs'
  ],

  afterShow: function(instance, current) {

    var url = window.location.href;
    var cat = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('#') + 1);
    var cats = cat.split('-');
    catId = cats[0];
    var toolbar = "<div id='tools'>" + $('#addscetion div').eq(this.index).html() + "</div>";
    var index = catId + $("[data-fancybox-index]").html();
    $('.fancybox-slide').children(".imagecontainer").remove();

    // This is the div content that I am appending
   $(".fancybox-slide").html('');
   $(".fancybox-slide").append(toolbar);
   $(".fancybox-slide").append($('#' + index).html());


  },
  caption: function(instance, obj) {
    return '<div><p class="fancy-nav"><a data-fancybox-prev title="Previous" tabindex="1">&lsaquo;</a> <a data-fancybox-next title="Next" tabindex="2">&rsaquo;</a> &nbsp; <span data-fancybox-index></span> of <span data-fancybox-count></span> images</p>' + $(this).find('.caption').html() + '</div>';
  },

  onInit: function(instance) {
    instance.$refs.container.on('touchstart', '[data-fancybox-info]', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();

      instance.$refs.container.toggleClass('fancybox-vertical-caption');
    });
    instance.$refs.container.on('mouseenter', '[data-fancybox-info]', function(e) {
      instance.$refs.container.addClass('fancybox-vertical-caption');
      instance.$refs.caption.one('mouseleave', function(e) {
        instance.$refs.container.removeClass('fancybox-vertical-caption');
      });

    });
    instance.$refs.container.on('click', '[data-fancybox-captionimg]', function(e) {
      $(".fancybox-image").attr("src", this.src);
    });
    instance.$refs.container.on('click', '[data-fancybox-captionbtn]', function(e) {
      $('.fancyRightCont').slideToggle('slow');
    });

  }

});
```

Comment: I want to display a text image over every images.
In script file
(".fancybox-slide").append("<div class='centerdivCont'></div>");
$(".fancybox-slide").append($('#'+index).html());
the above code is working well. But the centerdiv class is appended twice when clicking next buttons in fancy box

Comment: On click images, No image is showing. Instead showing "undefined".

Comment: Ok than parse HTML from your PHP code and put it in your question. then we will move further.

Comment: My original code was working well except the div is appended twice. I just wanted to append it only once for each image.

Comment: Yes, I understand the scenario. but I wanted it to replicate so I can solve it for you.

Comment: what shall I have t give to you?

Comment: i need parsed HTML and JS from your side. you are using PHP right? so you need to add demo working data instead of PHP code.